# bring many years (oracle plsql)

Tags: sql, oracle

[image]
hi this query bring for "one year 2020" ; but, i want to bring this query.

```
state_name ,2020 total deaths ,2021 total deaths
```

Comment: Please share the query. Images are not the proper way to ask question on SO.

Comment: SELECT S.STATENAME, SUM(ST.DEATH) FROM COVID.STATECASES1 ST
INNER JOIN COVID.STATE_ S ON S.STATECODE = ST.STATECODE
WHERE ST.DATE_ BETWEEN '01.01.2020' AND '31.12.2020'
GROUP BY S.STATENAME
ORDER BY S.STATENAME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option might be

```
select 
  s.statename, 
  sum(case when extract(year from st.date_) = 2020 then st.death end) deaths_2020,
  sum(case when extract(year from st.date_) = 2021 then st.death end) deaths_2021
from statecases1 st join state_ s on s.statecode = st.statecode
group by s.statename
order by s.statename;
```

Your query can't return data for 2020 and 2021 because of the `WHERE` clause you used (you restricted dates to year 2020).

Comment: It's not really wrong, but the `EXTRACT` function returns a number, (for the year). This leads to an implicit conversion, which I would avoid.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this. Although i am not 100% clear but this is what i thought you need - sum by state and year. You can also use `pivot`.

```
WITH yearly_data AS
  (SELECT s.statename, to_char(st.date_, 'YYYY') AS YEAR, sum(death) death
   FROM covid.statecases1 st
   JOIN covid_state_ s ON s.statecode=st.statecode
   GROUP BY s.statename, to_char(st.date_, 'YYYY'))
SELECT DISTINCT a.statename, b.death 2020_death,c.death 2021_death
FROM yearly_data a
LEFT JOIN yearly_data b ON a.statename=b.statename AND b.year='2020'
LEFT JOIN yearly_data c ON a.statename=c.statename AND c.year='2021'
ORDER BY 1
```

Comment: `yearly_data` will contain 2020 data only, because of the WHERE clause `to_char(st.date_, 'YYYY')='2020'`

Comment: sorry, it was a mistake. fixed it